# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘setState’ of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am trying to display a star rating, but I get an error.
The error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘setState’ of undefined`.

```
class Foo extends Component {
 changeRating( newRating, name ) {
  this.setState({
  rating: newRating
  });
}
render() {
 return (
  <StarRatings
    rating={this.setState.rating}
    starRatedColor=“blue”
    changeRating={this.changeRating}
    numberOfStars={5}
    name=‘rating’
    starDimension=“20px”
    starSpacing=“8px”    
  />
);
  }
}
```

Can anyone guide me on how to solve this?

Comment: Define the state first! Check my Answer !!

Comment: Don't forget to bind events..  `this.changeRating = this.changeRating.bind(this);` in your constructor.

Comment: try https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qej9ke

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. Your `changeRating` function is not bound to your class context, leading to the error you get. This can be solved with an arrow function.
2. You are getting your value using `this.setState` instead of `this.state`

Here is how you can fix both :

```
class Foo extends Component {
  changeRating = (newRating, name) => {
    this.setState({
      rating: newRating
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StarRatings
        rating= {this.state.rating}
        starRatedColor =“blue”
        changeRating = { this.changeRating }
        numberOfStars = { 5}
        name =‘rating’
        starDimension =“20px”
        starSpacing =“8px”
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I would also advise setting a default value for your rating by either defining it in the state or using the null operator :

```
rating= {this.state.rating || "my default value"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo extends Component {
 changeRating( newRating, name ) {
  this.setState({
  rating: newRating
  });
}
render() {
 return (
  <StarRatings
    rating={this.setState.rating}
    starRatedColor=“blue”
    changeRating={this.changeRating}
    numberOfStars={5}
    name=‘rating’
    starDimension=“20px”
    starSpacing=“8px”    
  />
);
  }
}
```

You haven't bind your function to this instance.
So use arrow function and you are good to go

```
changeRating = ( newRating, name ) => {
      this.setState({
      rating: newRating
      });
    }
```

Comment: You are missing an `=` before the arguments for you arrow function syntax to be valid

Answer (score 0):

The `changeRating` function isn't binded or an arrow function, so it doesn't have access to `this`. As said by the other answer, either use arrow function or if you are aware of performance use bind doing:

```
this.changeRating= this.changeRating.bind(this) //inside your constructor
```

Answer (score -1):

Define the state first! and also use arrow function

```
class Foo extends Component {
     state = {
      rating: ""
      }

 changeRating( newRating, name ) {
  this.setState({
  rating: newRating
  });
}
render() {
 return (
  <StarRatings
    rating={this.State.rating} // CHANGE
    starRatedColor=“blue”
    changeRating={() => this.changeRating} // CHANGE
    numberOfStars={5}
    name=‘rating’
    starDimension=“20px”
    starSpacing=“8px”    
  />
);
  }
}
```

Comment: Defining the state is not mandatory and won't cause an error, the state variable is called `this.state` and your new `changeRating` function is not receiving any parameters